# Excel - calculate time frame between dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How can I show the amount of time between the first and second (or third, etc...) purchase for every customer (by their email address)?

[image]

Comment: how do you want to do it? adding a new column showing time elapsed since last / until next purchase? Creating a pivot table listing dime intervals?

Comment: Please don't post people's email addresses on public web sites without them knowing about it. If these are fake emails, ignore my comment.

Comment: I replaced the screenshot with a version that hides the full email addresses but still shows which rows have the same email address.

Comment: Máté Juhász i want to crate new colum showing the days that passed since the 1st purchase, 2nd purchase for each customer.

Comment: Is your interval between successive purchases or all in reference to the first purchase?  Please edit the question to add what the results should like like for your example.

Comment: Adding to @fixer1234's comment, can you guarantee the purchase dates for each customer are sorted in ascending order?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

1. You wish to calculate the time difference between each two consecutive purchases of the same customer.
2. Each customer's purchases are sorted by date in ascending order.

Here's an example formula I used for cell D2 in the screenshot below:

`=IF(C2=C1, INT(A2-A1) & " Days " & TEXT(A2-A1, "h:mm") & " Hours", "")`

You can autofill this formula for the rest of the rows in column D. The result looks like this:

[image]